# How to use generic class in Xamarin SQLite Project

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, generics

I'm working on a software that uses a SQLite local database in Xamarin.
I'm using Microsoft's Todo sample as a base.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

In this sample, only Todo is stored, so the only class that accesses SQLite is TodoItemDatabase.
In the software we are building, we are planning to access multiple tables such as Todo, Memo, Diary, and so on.
In that case, we need to create TodoItemDatabase, MemoItemDatabase, and DiaryItemDatabase separately for each of them.
So, I decided to use generic classes in this case.

```
    public class BaseDatabase<T>
    {
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

        public static readonly AsyncLazy<ItemDatabase> Instance = new AsyncLazy<ItemDatabase>(async () =>
        {
            File.Delete(Constants.DatabasePath);

            var instance = new ItemDatabase();
            try
            {
                CreateTableResult result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<T>();
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                var error = exception.Message;
            }
            return instance;
        });

        public BaseDatabase()
        {
            Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        }

        public Task<List<T>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            return Database.Table<T>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<List<T>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
        {
            return Database.QueryAsync<T>("SELECT * FROM [Item] WHERE [Done] = 0");
        }

        public Task<T> GetItemAsync(string id)
        {
            return Database.Table<T>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(T item)
        {
            if (item.Id == null)
            {
                return Database.InsertAsync(item);
            }
            else
            {
                return Database.UpdateAsync(item);
            }
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(T item)
        {
            return Database.DeleteAsync(item);
        }
    }
```

However, when I replaced Task<List> with Task<List> and Task with Task as class BaseDatabase to make it a generic class, two errors occurred.
The first one is that
T must be a generic type or a non-abstract type with a constructor without public parameters to be used as parameter T in method SQLiteAsyncConnection.Table().
T does not contain an Id definition and no accessible extension method ItemId was found that accepts the first argument of type T.
How to solve these two problems?
Please let me know how to solve these two problems in the code of the generic class.

Answer (score 0):

> 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
> constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
> method 'SQLiteAsyncConnection.CreateTableAsync(CreateFlags)

Just as the tip mentioned,in your code, T must be a generic type or a non-abstract type with a constructor for funtion `SQLiteAsyncConnection.CreateTableAsync`
without public parameters

```
 CreateTableResult result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<T>();
```

So, you need use a common class to replace the `T` here.

> we are planning to access multiple tables such as Todo, Memo, Diary,
> and so on. In that case, we need to create TodoItemDatabase,
> MemoItemDatabase, and DiaryItemDatabase separately for each of them

In a database, you can create many tables inside it instead of creating a database for a every table.

In summary, you can create a table one by one inside of your database.

You can refer to the following code:

```
    public class TodoItemDatabase
    {
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

        public static readonly AsyncLazy<TodoItemDatabase> Instance = new AsyncLazy<TodoItemDatabase>(async () =>
        {
            var instance = new TodoItemDatabase();
            CreateTableResult result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>();

            CreateTableResult result_memo = await Database.CreateTableAsync<Memo>();

            CreateTableResult result_diary = await Database.CreateTableAsync<Diary>();


            return instance;
        });

        public TodoItemDatabase()
        {
            Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        }

        /*   query  funtion   */

        public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            return Database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<List<Memo>> GetItemsAsync_memo()
        {
            return Database.Table<Memo>().ToListAsync();
        }
         // other code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understand how to make the table.
I have a question.
GetItemAsync/GetItemAsnc_memo codes are almost identical and duplicate each other.
Is there any way to standardize them using T, generic, or some other method?

Comment: You can create a parent class, and make other tables class extends this parent  class.  And  you can do Type conversion when used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but not exactly answered.  I ran into this issue as well and was searching on how to solve the issue, and stumbled upon this post so I'll put this here:

> 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
> constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
> method 'SQLiteAsyncConnection.CreateTableAsync(CreateFlags)

As it states, it must be non-abstract and and have a parameterless constructor, to do so, take your DatabaseService and add this to the class definition:

```
class BaseDatabase<T> where T : new()
```

This will allow you to continue to use the generic type.  I have yet to fully test it out in my scenario, so I apologize if I am pointing at things wrong (and will edit if I find otherwise or other constraints).

Source for constraint options:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters